# How to find no of users in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, case-when

I have table like below

```
A       B    C    D 
part1   p    NA   NA
part2   NA   NA    p
Part3   p     p    NA
```

I have to create table with part1 users,part2 users and part3 users. p represents users.

I have tried like below for part1 users but is giving all part1 and part2 and part3 users as 1.

```
SELECT count(distinct A) as no_of_part1_users 
    FROM table1
    WHERE (A="part1" AND B="x") OR (A="part1" AND C="x") OR (A="part1" AND D="x");
```

I am getting output like below:

```
no_of_part1_users
1
```

I have applied same logic for part2 and part3 users but i am getting same output.

Desired output:

```
no_of_part1_users   no_of_part2_users no_of_part3_users
1                        1                 2
```

Comment: You should probably change your table design to just have a single column if you really plan on doing this query often.

Comment: I have tried to pivot the table but not successfully completed.pivot is not there in mysql

Comment: Yep, this kind of problem is highly suggestive of poor schema design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce what you want, you could use a `FROM`-less `SELECT` with subqueries for each count. Each subquery uses a derived table that transforms the columns into rows using `UNION ALL`. Then this can be filtered and the count being taken.

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*)
               FROM (SELECT b u
                            FROM table1
                            WHERE a = 'part1'
                     UNION ALL
                     ...
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT d u
                            FROM table1
                            WHERE a = 'part1') x
               WHERE u <> 'NA') no_of_part1_users,
       ...
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM (SELECT b u
                            FROM table1
                            WHERE a = 'part3'
                     UNION ALL
                     ...
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT d u
                            FROM table1
                            WHERE a = 'part3') x
               WHERE u <> 'NA') no_of_part3_users;
```

But yeah, that's pretty ugly. Your design is really bad indeed. You should really fix that instead. Relational tables aren't spreadsheets!

Comment: Okay.i'll fix my table.